# Microsoft SQL -- struggles with CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql-server

So i have to do a cartesian product (or CROSS JOIN) between two tables. One problem is that both tables have a column with the name 'itemname'. My current case looks as follows:

```
select *
into #cartesian_temp
from xsale CROSS JOIN xitem

delete from #cartesian_temp where deptname='books' and itemcolor='bamboo'

select * from #cartesian_temp
```

so the error I get is:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'itemname' in table '#cartesian_temp' is specified more than once

Anyone that can help me with my problem?

Comment: Don't use select *? You should specify which columns you want. And if you really do want both columns you will need to alias one of them in your query.

Comment: i indeed need both columns, how should i do it then with the alias way? because i tried different methods but none helped me to get the alias. Probably because I'm new in SQL and used the wrong methods. Maybe you can help me with which i should use?

Comment: you should remove * and select all of the columns and put alias for one of those columns,just that

Comment: @Abolfazl i did what you said.  My code is now: 

select saleno, saleqty, itemname AS itemname1, deptname
into #cartesian_temp
from xsale CROSS JOIN xitem
delete from #cartesian_temp where deptname='books' and itemcolor='bamboo'
select * from #cartesian_temp
But now the CROSS JOIN doesn't work anymore. The error i get is; 'Ambiguous column name 'itemname'.'

Comment: Because you should alias your objects, @CalvinHuang , and prefix your columns. `itemname AS itemname1` is that `xsale.itemname` or `xitem.itemname`? SQL Server doesn't know, and therefore the error.

Comment: it worked, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

you can add alias for the columns like below.

select XS.itemname as saleitemname , XI.itemname as saleitemname2
into #cartesian_temp
from xsale XS CROSS JOIN xitem XI

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why seasoned SQL pro's will ALWAYS advocate to give Tables an alias and to ALWAYS fully qualify every column name by using the alias. It's not just a cross join problem

Avoid this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  person 
  INNER JOIN
  address
  ON addressid = address.id -- Person.addressid
```

Sure, it'll work as long as the column names are all unique (it'll probably cause issues even now because person will have an I'd column and so will address) but it might stop working at any point in future if someone adds columns to either table with names that clash

Prefer this:

```
SELECT p.id as personid, a.id as addressid, p.name, a.zipcode
FROM 
  person p
  INNER JOIN
  address a
  ON p.addressid = a.id
```

This is fully aliased (both tables have an alias) and we haven't used select *; weve fully qualified every column with a prefix using the table alias and we've aliased columns that have the same named (the ID columns) in each table so we can tel them apart. No one can add any columns to the db and cause this query to stop working

Aliasing Tables helps in another way; it lets us use the same table twice in a query. Suppose a person had a work address and a home address:

```
SELECT ...
FROM 
  person p
  INNER JOIN
  address awork
  ON p.workaddressid = awork.id

  INNER JOIN
  address ahome
  ON p.homeaddressid = ahome.id
```

This is impossible without aliasing. Always give aliases a sensible name (not a1, a2)

For your case, go like:

```
SELECT xs.itemname as xsitemname, xi.itemname as xiitemname, ...
FROM
  xsale xs 
  CROSS JOIN
  xitem xi
WHERE
  xi.itemcolor = 'green'
```

This will be every green item crossed with every sale item